# Django group by with variable

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-queryset

```
truncate_date = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('month', 'created')
qs = Order.objects.extra({'month':truncate_date})
report = qs.values('month', 'location').annotate(Count('pk'))
```

In this example I would like to pass values by variable, in previous lines I have some if's and depends on it I need to group by my results. 
Instead of 'month','location' there should be variable like my_list. I tried to convert it with join and map, but every time I get an error.

Comment: just use the variables: `report = qs.values(my_list).annotate(Count('pk'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, you're looking for [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments). In case when a function expects separate arguments, and you have those arguments in a list or tuple you should use `*` to unpack the values as separate. There's a similar syntax `**` for the case with dictionaries.

In you case, try:

```
my_list = ['month', 'location']
truncate_date = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('month', 'created')
qs = Order.objects.extra({'month':truncate_date})
report = qs.values(*my_list).annotate(Count('pk'))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a list of wanted values you can use the `*` syntax:

```
truncate_date = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('month', 'created')
qs = Order.objects.extra({'month':truncate_date})
value_list = ['month', 'location']
report = qs.values(*value_list).annotate(Count('pk'))
```